Looking for ADCD cckd files for download for hercules install
I'm trying to setup a Hercules Mainframe emulator, but can't find the ADCD / cckd files needed to complete the setup. Anyone know where I can find them for download.

Those file are not free.  You need to purchase ADCD and I don't think IBM will allow you to purchase it to run on Hercules.
For more infomation:
http://dtsc.dfw.ibm.com/MVSDS/%27HTTPD2.ADCD.GLOBAL.SHTML(A31AREAD)%27
And search for "Accessing the ADCD z/OS 3.1 December 2023 Edition"
